# Use of という over に in this sentence

Tags: grammar

I've come across a sentence in a story and although I understand the meaning, I still find that という for me is a construction that I often struggle with a little bit.

On this occasion I'm wondering why という was used over に:

> 悟はカップを受け取って、何の気なし**という**様子で尋ねた。

It probably doesn't change the meaning a great deal at all, but I was wondering what nuance the author was trying to convey (if any) using という here.

Comment: You might want to add the alternate sentence with に in your question. Did you mean `何の気なしに尋ねた`? As Cerceis says, `何の気なしに様子で尋ねた` makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

「何の気なし**に**様子で尋ねた」 does not makes sense to me at all and it is weird to read. Another meaning you can decipher from `という` is `のような/のように`。 In this particular sentence, it means `as if`, which `に` does not have the similar meaning here.